# boost 1.74+ jni ndk compilation cmake project

Tags: boost, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to compile boost for Android JNI CMake project.
I tried with this repo
https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android

but fail build for boost v1.78 with ndk23..

Is there any tutorial or prebuilt how to do it on CMakeLists.txt project.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://github.com/Orphis/boost-cmake in my CMake Android NDK projects and it works fine, you can look at this project https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-vsomeip-hello-world as a reference. The only extra thing you need to do is add [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-vsomeip-hello-world/blob/master/cmake/FindBoost.cmake) to serve `find_package( Boost )` if you use it in your cmake files.